# Rails Select and Group by summation Custom SQL Calls

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I have a table named sales, which has the following fields:

```
id (integer)
quantity (integer)
product_id (integer)
payment_method (string - bad I know)
```

I want to hook these records up to the google visualization api but first I need to actually get the data presentable in the way that I want. The google visualization integration is not the issue. What IS the issue is that I can't seem to get the `group()` function or `select()` function to do what I want.

I'm not sure that group is what I want, but basically I would like to do a sales totals per product by `payment_method`.

My original idea was that it would look like

```
.select("SUM(quantity) as total_sold", :product_id).group(:payment_method)
```

But that doesn't really help me sort them by product. What I'd like the data to look like would be:

```
CASH SALES:
    Product A: 103 sales
    Product B: 32 sales
    Product C: 87 sales
CREDITCARD SALES:
    Product A: 23 sales
    Product B: 43 sales
    Product C: 12 sales
DONATION SALES:
    Product A: # sales
    Product B: 43 sales
    Product C: 12 sales
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
.select("SUM(quantity) as total_sold", :product_id).group(:payment_method, :product_id)
```

Here first it will group the result set by payment method, then by product id.

Comment: I keep getting the error: "Argument Error: Wrong number of arguments (2 for 1) from query_methods.rb. Any thoughts?

Comment: I think we cannot pass two parameters for select method, so please make it as .select("SUM(quantity) as totla_sold, product_id")

Comment: Still no dice on passing them all in one string. I tried it with product_id and :product_id. Same thing with quantity and :quantity

Answer (score 0):

Keep the select of all columns inside of one string.  Generated SQL will use that "as is".  No need to close the string and put 2nd parameter as symbol `:product_id` in select.
Important to add all columns from group by in select also.
Consider `.order("payment_method, product_id")` also.

```
.select("SUM(quantity) as total_sold, payment_method, product_id").group(:payment_method, :product_id)
```

Tested using rails console:

```
Product.select("product_line_id, public_product_id pp_id, count(product_id) num_products") .group("product_line_id, public_product_id").map{|p| "Public Prod Id: #{p.pp_id} has #{p.num_products} products " }
```

> Product Load (0.2ms)  SELECT public_product_id pp_id, count(product_id) num_products FROM `products` GROUP BY `products`.`public_product_id`
>   => [
>   "Public Prod Id: 5 has 1 products ", 
>   "Public Prod Id: 6 has 2 products ", 
>   "Public Prod Id: 8 has 1 products ", ... ]